# Separate a string into two

Tags: node.js

Let's say a user inputs

> I need; help

How do I make it so split the string into two from that semicolon, like, for instance: `str1 = "I need"; str2 = "help;"`?
I am aware this is a pretty basic question, but I am pretty new to Nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split(";")` and use `;` as your split string, this will result in an array of two entries in this case.

```
var parts = "I need;help".split(";");
var str1 = parts[0].trim(); // will be "I need"
var str2 = parts[1].trim(); // will be "help"
```

Comment: `typeof str1 === 'function'`

Answer (score -1):

String split() Method.

var str = "I need; help"
var res = str.split(";");

res = [I need, help]